# Issue of Identifing input from scanner device or Manual entry

Tags: javascript, jsp, input, scanning

I have one different challenge right now. I am working to design a web page where user can use scanning device to enter long serial number or they can do it manually by key board to enter values in JSP text boxes. I need to identify the input type(manual or scanner entry) for each such field and display with different styles on result page.

Can any one help me with this how we can do that? I have found one way to do it through java script. Writing a JS function on key press which will count and maintain the number of keys pressed. If count goes beyond the 17 digits its manual entry else scanner entry. But this idea do not sound that good as well as might not be the efficient way and my manager also did not like it. Can you suggest any other options or just modification to the idea I mentioned?

Thanks in Advance..!! I really appriciate if you can help me in my situation.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just measure the time it takes to enter the code? If it's faster than a certain time (starting when the first digit was entered), it's from a scanner?

Comment: Thanks Stefan for quick response..!! 

Can you please share some more details how we can measure time?
and yes it's from scanner like we see in walmart or any grocery stores to read a barcode. it just automaticall populates the value to the field which you have selected.

and just one more question do you think the option which I have mentioned in question is a reliable option?

Comment: Use Date.now() to obtain the current time in milliseconds and store it somewhere on the first keypress in a given field. When the last digit is entered, compare the stored time to Date.now(). If the difference is small enough, the number was entered via a scanner.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I used this time measurement and after all the research I came to conclusion that this is the only way to handle this situation. 

This is just for information that first approach which I mentioned with counting keys manually pressed with onkeypress event is not useful at all as scanner also uses the keyboard interface and scanner also triggers the onkeypress event for each number.

Comment: Thanks for the update! If the answer is correct, you may want to accept it (add the green checkmark to mark the question as answered)